# To Execute Statement Repeatedly

Tags: java

My desired output is 1,4,9 and 16 but im stuck. Does anyone knows what is wrong with my      coding?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication1 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);   

    int i = 4;
    int j = 3;
    int x =  ;

    while(i >= 1){
  }


       x = (i-j)*(i-j);
       i = i-1;
       j = j-2;

    System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a paper and a pencil and write the values you get at each iteration for i, j and x. You will see what happens and be able to correct it and get the desired output.

Comment: Or.. use a DEBUGGER! It's there to help you.

Comment: I know what's wrong with your coding - you're doing it too fast and as a result getting bogged down with unnecessary complexity that could've been avoided by thinking this through beforehand. Type less, think more!

Comment: But it's still compiled with errors :(

Comment: @user2971157 What you have put there doesn't compile. `{}`

Comment: As Philip subtly hints, check your braces `{}`. Matching braces are a must - and your loop lacks the closing one.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse I can't quite figure out SO's code formats either. whenever I copy-paste my code the class closing bracket will always be outside the grey field :D

Comment: @user2651804 You just need to indent all your code by four spaces. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you want is a function that squares the x value. There are a wide array of possibilities, but yours seems a little weird. If you're not familiar with the Math class, you should: only have a single variable, x, starting at 1. Ask wether x is less than 5 (you only want to iterate 4 times). Make the computer execute x*x.

Like so:

```
int x =  1;

while(x < 5){
  System.out.println(x*x);
  x++; //the computer will interpret this as x = x+1
}
```

Comment: This will print 1,2,3,4 (each on a separate line). It should be `System.out.println(x*x);`